# Random reference errors with Google login on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-api, google-plus

I'm new to Google's API and I'm trying to set up a sign in button. Followed their instructions (both on youtube and on google developers) but while trying to compile, I get 19(!!) errors:

some are:

> Linker command failed with exit code 1

and

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary" referenced from
obj-class-ref in GooglePlus (NSData+GPPAdditions.o)
obj-class-ref in GooglePlus (UIDevice+GPPAdditions.o)
```

This and more OBJC errors as well as addressbook errors and other libraries I haven't used (I'm only creating a sign in button, or at least trying to)

Comment: You need to add a few frameworks to your project. Look at the docs and see which one it says you need. `ALAssetsLibrary` requires the `AssetsLibrary` framework.

Comment: Nope, nothing like that in the docs - at least not for the signin button.

Comment: Figure out which frameworks contain the missing symbols and add the needed frameworks to your project.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is on the getting started page, located here:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started

3. Include the following frameworks in your Xcode project:

   - AddressBook.framework
   - AssetsLibrary.framework
   - Foundation.framework
   - CoreLocation.framework
   - CoreMotion.framework
   - CoreGraphics.framework
   - CoreText.framework
   - MediaPlayer.framework
   - Security.framework
   - SystemConfiguration.framework
   - UIKit.framework